# An estimate for the ideal class number of the quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ when $d<-3$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

There is a formula given in the Exercise 24 of Marcus' *Number Fields*(page 212):

Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ where $d<-3$ is squarefree. Then

> $$h\le \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k\in Z_m^*,k<m/2}(m-2k),$$

where $m$ is the discriminant of $K$.

The hint says we can use the fact that 
$|L(1,\chi)|=\frac{\pi}{m\sqrt m}|\sum_{k\in Z_m^*}\chi(k)k|$, but I don't know what relation between $L(1,\chi)$ and the class number $h$ we should use here in order to get the estimate above.